# Android/Java Servlet connection lost on return

Tags: java, android, servlets, timeout

I have a really big problem happening on my application.

I call the servlet to insert a sell in the database.

My application wait for the return to show the message to user.

The servlet had inserted the sell, but at the moment to return the result, it lost the connection and it returns null.

For my application, the sell hadn't inserted, but it had.

Then the user have to do the operation again, and the sell will be duplicated.

Can I avoid this kind of thing?

This is the code I use to do my requisitions

```
try {
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 3000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout        (httpParams, 20000);

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
        HttpPost   httpPost   = new HttpPost(url_requisicao);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        // Post output
        if (json != null) {
            HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        }

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder json_retorno = new StringBuilder();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            json_retorno.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        retorno = json_retorno.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I've the same problem, I can't get this solved and still I'm getting sometimes the headache because the problem to fix up the database...

Comment: try                               HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 0);
     HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout        (httpParams, 0);

Comment: It is not about timeout, and so by poor connections